# list.save and list.distUpgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, software-sources

This is more of a curiosity question as I try to get a better understanding of apt and package management.

I'm seeing that in my `/etc/apt/` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folders I have very or sometimes identical files which have the extension of `sources.list`, `sources.list.distUpgrade`, `sources.list.save`, and so on.

What's the point of these duplicate or similar files?

`sources.list` and `sources.list.save` in `/etc/apt/` seem to be identical but `sources.list.distUpgrade` shows *quantal* instead of *raring* for most stuff (I probably first installed *quantal*).

On the other hand, in the case of `google-talkplugin.list` and `google-talkplugin.listUpgrade` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` the content of the files seems to be completely identical.

Didn't find much in Google searches. I reviewed [the sources.list manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man5/sources.list.5.html) but it didn't talk much about it.

Also noticed [this article](http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/08/27/solved-ignoring-file-distupgrade-save-in-directory-etcaptsources-list-d-as-it-has-an-invalid-filename-extension-on-ubuntu-10-10/) where [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/631770) related to the extensions was noted for 10.10

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I am not sure about sources.list.distUpgrade, but the sources.list.save file is a backup of the sources.list file.  I know from personal experience (about 5 minutes ago) that the sources.list.save file is extremely important after attempting to add a repository.  If  software center stops working correctly (EX: closing right after starting) then you need to replace the current sources.list file with the sources.list.save file.

To do this, open a new terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and type the command

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.save /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This should fix the corrupt sources.list as long as sources.list.save exists in the /etc/apt/ directory.

**Simply put, sources.list.save is just a backup file.**

Comment: .distUpgrade is a backup of the source state prior to running a dist-upgrade since third party sources are commented out due to unknown compatibility with the newer distribution.

Comment: @GregL83 Thanks! Could you add that as an answer?

Comment: @wjandrea when I look at when this comment was made and that this user was inactive since April 2017 I heavily doubt  that this will yield any result.

Comment: At what point is this .save backup file created and by which process? I noticed it is not always present.

Answer (score 2):

I was concerned about whether these files are included in the repos used when updating etc packages. It seems they're not: From `man sources.list` re. the `sources.list.d` directory:

> Filenames need to have either the extension `.list` or `.sources` depending on the contained format.

it goes on to talk about ignoring files. In summary I take it to mean that only files with `.list` or `.sources` get used when updating packages etc. The meaning of the `.save` and `.distUpgrade` files is well explained in the existing answer from Strato1 and the comments there.